# QT Detecting if the return keyis pressed and released or if it is long pressed

Tags: qt, qkeyevent

I am using QT on Windows 10.

I am using a QDialog where I want to push the QPushButtons also with the return key.
However, I want that the user has to push the return key and release it again.
Long pressing the return key should work only once and not several times.

I checked the keyPressEvent and the keyReleaseEvent, but unfortunately when I do a long press with the return key, I get continuously keyReleaseEvent and keyPressEvent.

Any ideas, how I can detect if the return key is long pressed or how I can I disable the long pressed functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can start the timer in keyPressEvent and  in keyReleaseEvent read elapsed

```
QElapsedTimer mTimer;
keyPressEvent ()
{
  .....
  mTimer.start();
  .....
}
keyReleaseEvent ()
{
  .....
  int mMilliseconds = mTimer.elapsed();
  .....
}
```

and you can set the label for a long press

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but the workaround works and I can live with that.
Thanks a lot